# Gmail stopped sending PHPmailer messages (was previously working, now marking as spam?)

Tags: email, gmail, phpmailer

My application uses PHPMailer to send email through gmail.  It was previously working fine, but it appears maybe now gmail is categorizing my email as spam before it is sent out to the recipients.  Below is an example of one of the messages that were rejected.  I removed URL and Email addresses to protect the innocent.  Is this as simple as making t he email body text better so it isn't seems as spam, or is there a more precise fix for this?

```
    Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     <removed@removed.com>

Technical details of permanent failure:
Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

----- Original message -----

X-Received: by 10.60.144.196 with SMTP id so4mr19216383oeb.66.1439493466614;
        Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:17:46 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <removed@removed.com>
Received: from www.example...realurlhere.com ([x.x.x.x])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id w135sm1602558oie.25.2015.08.13.12.17.45
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:17:45 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 15:17:45 -0400
To: <removed@removed.com>, <removed@removed.com>, <removed@removed.com>
From: <removed@removed.com>
Reply-To: <removed@removed.com>
Subject: Spot Bid Request Sent to you - Shipment Request ID: XX
Message-ID: <04b4cbfac43b29b8810d7d8b1c61b349@www.url.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="b1_04b4cbfac43b29b8810d7d8b1c61b349"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit



Spot Bid Request Sent to you - Shipment Request ID: xx
System Login:  http://www.url.....example.com
```

Comment: Have you considered [reading what the error says](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585)?

Comment: Synchro, yes sir, I have read the error "Message Rejected" and been googling this since noon of yesterday.  I have also looked at the link gmail references, but it is very vague in terms of any answer.  Am I missing something in regards to if there is more explanation of the error in the message?

Comment: Going by what they say, the most obvious thing is that you are sending to multiple recipients at once - try sending one at a time, make sure your from address is correct (i.e. an authorised account or predefined alias since gmail does not allow arbitrary from addresses). You should also check your SPF records and look into signing with DKIM.

Comment: Synchro - Thank you very much.  this is perfect as I just needed a nudge in the right direction.  I will work on these steps.  Thank you again.